# F# yield! operator - Implementation and possible C# equivalents

Tags: c#, f#, ienumerable, yield, enumerators

I'm currently learning F# and I really love the `yield!` (yield-bang) operator. Not only for its name but also for what it does of course.

The `yield!` operator basically allows you to yield all elements of a sequence from a sequence expression. This is useful for composing enumerators. Since I regularly encounter big, complicated enumerators I am interested in strategies we can use to break them up and compose them from simpler enumerators.

Unfortunatetely, the `yield!` operator is not available in C#. As far as I understand, what it does is like a `foreach (var x in source) yield x;` but the book I'm reading ([Petricek's Real World F# - Manning](http://manning.com/petricek/)) suggests that it has better performance...

- So what exactly does the F# compiler do here? (Yes, I can look at it using Reflector too but I'd like to have a more detailed description of the mechanism).

In order to achieve a similar construct in C# I have explored multiple ways, but none of them is as concise as the `yield!` operator and I'm also not sure about the complexity of them. Could someone please provide input if my BigO numbers are correct?

- Decompose enumerator into multiple private enumerators and then yield each element from the public enumerator:

  ```
  foreach (var x in part1()) yield x
  foreach (var x in part2()) yield x
  ```

  This will effectively result in a "double yield" on each element. Is that O(2n) then? (or possibly worse?) Anyway, using this approach stops me from using `yield break;` from any of my subparts.
- Decompose enumerator into multiple private enumerators and then concat all private enumerators from the public enumerator:

  ```
  return part1().Concat(part2())
  ```

  I believe this is no different from the aforementioned solution because `Concat()` is implemented the way I outlined above.

Any other options?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding how the compiler translates the `yield!` operation, [the paper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/specsharp/iterators.pdf) cited by Thomas Levesque in his answer illustrates one implementation technique in section 4.3 (in particular, their example spanning figures 7-9 is illustrative of the general strategy).  I don't think that there's any good way to do this from within an iterator block in C# - as I understand your proposed solutions, they could both result in quadratic behavior when used recursively.  You could always manually create a `NestedEnumerable<T>` subclass to achieve the performance benefits, but this will be quite ugly compared to using a normal iterator block.

Answer (score 7):

In the current version of C#, I don't think you have other options than `foreach... yield return` and `Concat`. I agree it would be nice to have the `yield!` operator in C#, it would make certain constructs much more elegant, but I doubt this feature will ever make it to the "must-have" list, since we can easily do without it.

You might be interested in this [MS research paper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/specsharp/iterators.pdf), which introduces a new `yield foreach` construct :

```
IEnumerable<XmlNode> Traverse(XmlNode n)
{
    yield return n;
    foreach (XmlNode c in n.ChildNodes)
        yield foreach Traverse(c);
}
```

Regarding your question about complexity: in both cases it's *O(n)*. *O(2n)* is not used, because it denotes the same complexity as *O(n)* (linear). I don't think you can do better than that with the current C# features...

Comment: As the paper you cite points out, when used recursively there are instances where `yield!` (which is equivalent to the hypothetical `yield foreach` in C#) is O(n) but  `foreach ... yield return ...` is O(n^2).

Comment: @kvb: Right, that was the one I'm talking about, sorry if this wasn't clear.

Answer (score 4):

There is no direct counterpart to `yield!` in C#. You're currently stuck with a combination of `foreach` and `yield return`.

However, IIRC, LINQ offers something similar, namely the `SelectMany` query operator, which translates to C# as multiple `from .. in ..` clauses.

(I'm hoping I'm not mixing up two different concepts, but IIRC, both `yield!` and `SelectMany` are essentially "flattening" projections; ie. a hierarchy of objects is "flattened" into a list.)